# Microsoft graph api is sending multiple duplicate "created" notifications on a message resource

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

The exact POST I made to create exactly 1 subscription on 1 resource:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "changeType": "created",
  "notificationUrl": "https://myurl.com/endpoint",
  "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime": "{{addMinutes(now; 4225)}}",
  "clientState": "{{uuid}}"
}
```

[Microsoft Graph notifications for changes in resource data Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?tabs=http)

What's weird is that sometimes it sends the same data to my URL 2 times, sometimes just 1, sometimes 3. I know they're duplicated because they're completely the same (I used a difftool).

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635975/multiple-change-notification-from-microsoft-graph?noredirect=1&lq=1), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412261/microsoft-graph-webhook-subscription-getting-multiple-post-to-my-notificationur), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910083/receiving-multiple-webhook-notifications-for-outlook-calendar-event) but I just couldn't understand why its possible to send out more than 1 webhook for a "created" notification. I'm responding with a 202 as soon as I get the POST and these duplicated POSTS are not even 1 second apart so not sure if I could store the "@odata.etag" and check if its already in a database as I use integromat to receive these change notifications.

So what gives? How can I make it so that I only receive 1 notification? Does it have something to do with how the mailbox is setup? Is storing the `@odata.etag` really the proper way to handle this? Really absurd if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to the known issues in Change notifications:

[image]

For information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#change-notifications